# What's the real differences between these two methods of fetching API data?

Tags: javascript, rest, next.js, fetch-api

I am querying third-party API in NextJS 14.  I have two pieces of code.  They both work but give a bit difference results.

**Method 1**, this is within /api folder as route handler:

```
export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/Client/GetAll`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TOKEN}`,
    },
  });
  const data = await res.json();

  return NextResponse.json({ data });
}
```

**Method 2**, similar to above but with try/catch block,

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TOKEN}`);

export async function GET() {
    try {
      const url = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/Client/GetAll`;
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
  
      const data = await response.json();
      return NextResponse.json({ data });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error; // Rethrow the error to handle it in the calling component
    }
}
```

The end result is that method 2 returns a more complete JSON data with everything that I need.  However the first method doesn't return everything.  It only returns like half of the data compared to the second method.

Any insights?

I tried both of the above method and I was hoping method 1 returns the same data from the API as method 2, but apparently it returns less data than expected.

Comment: The second checks the status code

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference in how headers are handled. in the first method, you're directly setting headers within the fetch call, but in the second method you're referencing headers variable, that u did not put in the code snippet. Also in the second code snippet you are using 'method: Get', but not in the first.

So the problem is with how you are handling fetch. If you will have same methods and headers, the result will be the same.

Comment: My understanding is that the default method for fetch such as this is "GET", why am I getting different results with and without the method: 'GET' in my code?